# Mysql - Finding cause of temp disk tables

Tags: mysql

I've recently noticed my MySQL server is creating a reasonably large number of disk tables [created temp disk tables: 67, created temp tables: 304].

I've been trying to identify what queries are creating these tables, but I've had no luck.  I've enabled the slow query log for queries taking more than 1 second, but the queries showing up in there don't make sense.  The only queries showing up regularly in the slow query log are updates to a single row on a user table, using the primary key as the where clause.

I've run 'explain' on all the queries that run regularly, and I'm coming up blank on the culprit.

Answer (score 7):

The EXPLAIN report may say "Using filesort" but that's misleading.  It doesn't mean it's writing to a file, it only means it's sorting without the benefit of an index.

The EXPLAIN report may say "Using temporary" but this doesn't mean it's using a temporary table on disk.  It can make a small temp table in memory.  The table must fit within the *lesser* of [max_heap_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_size) and [tmp_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size).  If you increase tmp_table_size, you should also increase max_heap_table_size to match.

See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html for more info on temporary table management.

But 4 gigs for that value is very high!  Consider that this memory can potentially be used *per connection*.  The default is 16 megs, so you've increased it by a factor of 256.

So we want to find which queries caused the temp disk tables.

If you run MySQL 5.1 or later, you can [SET GLOBAL long_query_time=0](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time) to make *all* queries output to the slow query log.  Be sure to do this only temporarily and set it back to a nonzero value when you're done!  :-)

If you run [Percona Server](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-server/), the [slow query log is extended](http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-server:features:slow_extended_51) with additional information and configurability, including whether the query caused a temp table or a temp disk table.  You can even filter the slow-query log to include only queries that cause a temp table or temp disk table (the docs I link to).

You can also process Percona Server's slow-query log with [mk-query-digest](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-query-digest.html) and filter for queries that cause a temp disk table.

```
mk-query-digest /path/to/slow.log --no-report --print \
  --filter '($event->{Disk_tmp_table }||"") eq "Yes"'
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using MySQL 5.6 or above, you can use the performance schema. Try something like:

```
select * from events_statements_summary_by_digest where SUM_CREATED_TMP_DISK_TABLES>0\G
```

Comment: This was super helpful! Thank you.

Comment: SELECT * FROM sys.statements_with_temp_tables; worked for me in 5.7.x

Answer (score 2):

Often queries using an `ORDER BY` will have to use temp table(s). If you run `EXPLAIN` on those queries you might see:

`using filesort ; using temporary tables`

Look for queries with an `ORDER BY`

Comment: Is there a reason they'd be using DISK tables?  My largest table is only 600 megs, but my temp table size for memory is set to have 4 gigs available.  It's strange that it would ever have to utilize a temporary disk table.

Comment: Some data types force a disk table too be used instead of a memory one. E.g. if you have a `blob` or `text` field in the select then ordering of the query might be forcing disk-based temp tables into play.

Comment: GROUP BY may also cause a temporary table, including GROUP BY with a text field. Better to make a CRC32 or something and group by it instead.