# find out what queries created ""tmp_disk_tables"

Tags: mysql

my status report says for mysql tells me that there were some tables which need to be stored on the HDD because they didnt fit int the cache memory. its not a big number, but i am puzzled by it.

```
Created_tmp_disk_tables 3.4 k
```

is there a way to find out what exact queries those were? so can i tell mysql to only log queries where "created tmp disk tables" is true?

i know that all my queries create tmp tables, i have a lot of joins and sorting, but my understanding of my queries is that most of those temp tables are really small. i set

```
tmp_table_size   = 256M
max_heap_table_size     = 256M
```

and IMO there just should not be any query which exceed this limit ever (no query should even be close to it)

I of course know the slow query log, but this has no information weather it created a disk table or not. I have found some topics covering this, but non of them seem to work in a stock mySQL 5.5 on a Debian7  (special patched version of mysql, mysql 5.6)

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/09/22/finding-what-created_tmp_disk_tables-with-log_slow_filter/

http://www.arubin.org/blog/2011/05/01/using-mysql-5-6-to-find-queries-creating-disk-temporary-tables/

(btw. if DB admin or server fault is a better place for this, sorry for the off topic)

Comment: Please see the reply here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848821/mysql-finding-cause-of-temp-disk-tables